# Tracing GET/POST calls

Tags: php, python, html, networking

is there a way to trace all the calls made by a web page when loading it? Say for example I went in a video watching site, I would like to trace all the GET calls recursively until I find an mp4/flv file. I know a way to do that would be to follow the URLs recursively, but this solution is not always suitable and quite limitative( say there's a few thousand links, or the links are in a file which can't be read). Is there a way to do this? Ideally, the implementation could be in python, but PHP as well as C is fine too

Comment: You could make a [MITM proxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) with Python and use that to transparently capture all of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://fiddler2.com/&ei=ysRxUc-uOsestAa_t4DADw&usg=AFQjCNHTxYGr6iTbxfd6U_SHLfIpIEmeLA&bvm=bv.45512109,d.Yms), wich is an extremely good web debugger proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of proxies (http://mitmproxy.org/ is popular, I really like http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which can MITM the HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome provides a built-in tool for seeing the network connections. Press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the JavaScript Console. Then open the Network tab to see all of the GET/POST calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FireFox or Chrome you could simply use the Developer Tools and filter all of the network requests with ".mp4" for example.

Or you could use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), and place a similar filter